# save picture into app folder

Tags: android

I'm really curious if it was possible to save a taken picture into Android's specific folder structure. To be more precise: I don't want it to be saved on the user's SD card but in the internal app folder (data/data/my.package/files).
Is this possible and a reasonable step (with regard to the memory capacity of the phone)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this.
If you in activity do next:

```
OutputStream is = openFileOutput("image.png");
```

Here you have OutputStream to files/ dir in app folder.

The method openFileOutput is form Context class. See this link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput(java.lang.String, int)

Hope it help you!

Comment: Brilliant!
And how can I read files from the internal memory?
Simply using "FileInputStream"? Seems like, that's not working here for me... everytime I'm using BufferedInputStream it says: "BufferedInputStream is not defined for *anyClassIChoose*"?